# Alternativas a «tirar de la cadena»

Tags: solicitud-de-término, diferencias-regionales, solicitud-de-modismo

[«Tirar de la cadena»](https://dle.rae.es/?id=6aZgEyV) es

> 1. loc. verb. Descargar la cisterna de un inodoro.

Proviene de los inodoros con cisterna en alto, cuya descarga se inicia jalando de una cadena.

Actualmente los inodoros suelen tener la cisterna unida y la descarga se inicia accionando una palanca o pulsador.

¿Cómo se debe decir en esos casos la acción de descargar la cisterna?

Comment: Very good, this is an obsolete phrase we discuss less than we should.

Comment: Alternatively, "apretar el botón" can be heard and is often used.

Comment: Una variante muy usada en mi país es "echar agua", sin embargo no se usa en el ámbito formal.

Answer (score 5):

Dado que "tirar de la cadena" se ha convertido en *locución adverbial*, ese es el nombre correcto para la acción, indistintamente del tipo de mecanismo. Cuando alguien dentro de unos años se pregunte porqué se le dice "cadena" si tiene otro mecanismo distinto, al buscar la etimología se dará cuenta de que antiguamente las cisternas funcionaban accionadas por una cadena.

Mis hijos suelen decir "darle a la palanca" porque es lo que tienen nuestros inodoros (una forma que es específica del mecanismo).

Recuerdo haber pensado sobre esta misma cuestión (supongo que es "deformación profesional" por culpa de este sitio), pararme a pensar que es imposible por su edad entiendan lo que significa (o significaba en su momento) el "tirar de la cadena" (creo que tengo algún Superhumor en casa con alguna historieta de Mortadelo en la que aparecen estos modelos antiguos, pero aparte de eso, como no viajen en el tiempo, creo que esos inodoros no los van a ver en la vida).

Tras caer en ello me he sorprendido alguna vez a mí mismo diciendo

> Dale al mecanismo (o Acciona el mencanismo)

al intentar buscar algo un poco más general (e independiente del tipo de mecanismo). También podrías decir

> Enjuagar el retrete/inodoro

Y esperar que tu interlocutor entienda el cómo hacerlo o a qué te refieres, indistintamente del mecanismo en cuestión.

Comment: En la región donde yo vivo, de vez en cuando me encuentro con algún bar que dispone de los modelos "de cadena".

Answer (score 4):

---

### **Tirar de la cadena**

De acuerdo con que la frase quedó obsoleta por estar asociada a la acción mecánica previa, reemplazada por el cambio tecnológico

Se podría adoptar una referencia directa a la función

> **Descargar / Desagotar / Vaciar el [ inodoro / retrete ]**

O, de forma más genérica

> **Hacer la descarga**

Hay más opciones, como

> **Purgar el sistema** 
>   (que suena algo raro, acaso eufemístico)

O haciendo foco en la parte humana de la interacción, usar alternativas como

> **Disparar / Iniciar [el vaciado / la descarga]**

o, simplemente

> **Accionar el mecanismo**

Answer (score 4):

En Venezuela utilizarías "bajar"

> Bajar [la poceta, el inodoro, etc.]

Comment: En México, también suele decirse: bájale... a la taza del baño, al wc, al inodoro, al baño, etc. Sé que decir bájale al baño, a la taza del baño o al wc es absurdo, pero mucha gente lo dice.

Answer (score 1):

Como han mencionado antes, la frase "tirar la cadena" ya no tiene sentido para mucha gente. En grandes ciudades hace años que se reemplazó el antiguo sistema de cisterna alta por sistemas donde se aprieta un botón o se acciona una palanca.

[image: antiguo inodoro con cisterna con cadena]

[image: inodoro moderno]

En Argentina, hoy en días las expresiones "tirar la cadena" y "apretar el botón" se usan como sinónimo y cualquier persona entiende la referencia incluso sin más contexto.

Comment: Una duda que me surge, ¿en Argentina se usa "tirar la cadena"? ¿sin la preposición "de"? No es ironía, es que lo pones dos veces y no tengo claro si es una errata o una variante idiomática.

Comment: @RubioRic Si, puedo confirmar que en Argentina el uso generalizado y persistente es `tirar la cadena` (sin la "de")