# ¿Cuál podría ser una alternativa para la expresión "embutido vegetal"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, solicitud-de-término

En los últimos años, estamos siendo testigos de un neologismo que, si he de ser sincero, a mí no me convence demasiado. Me refiero a la combinación **embutido vegetal**.

Si partimos de que el Diccionario de la Academia define [*embutido*](https://dle.rae.es/embutido) como

> 2. m. Tripa rellena con carne picada, principalmente de cerdo.
> 3. m. Tripa rellena de diversos ingredientes.

inicialmente podríamos aceptar la 3ª acepción como válida. Sin embargo, **tripa** es el "intestino" de un animal, y comoquiera que los *embutidos vegetales* tienen su razón de ser en que no pueden participar de este reino (el animal), entonces nos encontramos con el problema que precisamente no logro resolver.

En otras palabras: por lo expuesto hasta aquí ¿no habría que buscar una nueva palabra para estos productos?

Comment: Los conceptos evolucionan y lo que inicialmente tenía unos ingredientes (literalmente en este caso) puede cambiar manteniendo la denominación. Relacionado: [Alternativas a «tirar de la cadena»](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/31857/1674)

Comment: ¡Tienes razón! Seguramente tendré que aceptar el neologismo...

Comment: Sin embargo tienes razón, no hay necesidad de un neologismo "embutido vegetal" cuando puedes decir correctamente "embutido de vegetales".

Comment: Me gusta tu propuesta, porque además de certera es precisa.

Answer (score 2):

Lo cierto es que en este mundo cada vez más vegano, los conceptos más tradicionales como los que apuntas son aprovechados, sobre todo, por las grandes marcas para expandirse en un negocio cada día más creciente y rentable.

La forma comercial para llevarlo acabo e introducirse en ellos es relativamente simple, pues utilizan los nombres clásicos de productos habituales, elaborados con ingredientes cuyo contenido principal es la carne y a ellos se le añade la "coletilla", "vegana, vegetariana o vegetal", con lo que se consigue, por una parte, la reutilización del término para un uso distinto al original, y por otra, una clara identificación del producto, que facilita el reconocimiento casi instantáneo por parte del consumidor de unos componentes vegetales, usando nombres tradicionales, con lo que se gana en eficacia y rápido reconocimiento. Eso, antes que inventar nuevos modos, productos o nombres que en cualquier caso, entorpecerían o frenarían su rápida incorporación al mercado y cuya nueva conexión, consumidor-productos, sería más lenta.

De esta manera podemos difundir el concepto y hablar de salchichas vegetales o veganas, hamburguesas vegetales o veganas,... o embutido vegano, vegetal, vegetariano con propiedades opuestas a las originarias, es decir, aquellas que utilizan carne picada o productos relacionados, todo ello en aras por mantener y alejarse de cualquier comparativa que refuerce la idea original de producción.

En cuanto al nombre "**embutido vegetal**", y que no te convence demasiado, una opción que en parte alejaría el término del "reino animal", aunque da o mantiene una idea de su mismo modo o formato de elaboración, podría ser el término, "enfundado vegetal", pues da la misma idea de llenar y poner algo dentro de una funda, en este caso sería una funda fabricada artificialmente y no natural, como ocurre en el embutido, y que salvando esa cuestión "natural", en el fondo es lo mismo que se hace con el embutido tradicional.

---

Enfundar

https://dle.rae.es/enfundar?m=form

Comment: Tu propuesta es muy interesante.

Answer (score 0):

No todas las acepciones de la palabra embutido hacen referencia a productos cárnicos. De hecho se suele utilizar más a menudo con cualquiera de sus otros significados: enfundado, apretado, encajado, enquistado, incrustado, metido, empotrado.

> El conformado por estiramiento se usa ampliamente para el conformado de piezas ligeramente curvas con poca profundidad de **embutido** (ej. techos y puertas).

<sub>*[Fuente](https://www.autoform.com/es/glosario/embuticion-profunda/)*</sub>

> Kim Kardashian **embutida** en el vestido de Marilyn Monroe.

<sub>*[Fuente](https://theobjective.com/elsubjetivo/opinion/2022-05-06/kim-kardashian-vestido-marilyn-monroe/)*</sub>

> Puede instalar el grifo en una placa de pared o bien **embutido** en la pared.

<sub>*[Fuente](https://www.skil.es/instrucciones-paso-a-paso/instalar-un-grifo-exterior.html)*</sub>

Por lo que cualquier producto vegetal similar a uno cárnico por su forma o aspecto no debería ser interpretado en relación a un animal (por más que la hiperautosensibilización vegana así lo prefiera  ). De hecho deberíamos replantearnos casi todo el diccionario gastronómico: hamburguesa vegana, leche de soja, leche de almendras, azúcar de remolacha, cerveza sin alcohol, café descafeinado...

Pero sí se podría incluir la frase "embutido vegetal" si se acepta la versión de embutido como el procedimiento de crear alimentos en base a productos procedentes de animales al inmenso listado de pleonasmos que contiene el idioma español, como "comer comida" "completamente gratis" en una "negra noche" para que luego "termine acabando" en "heces fecales".